# Redux / React: modify a property of an object

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I'm trying to modify the value of my "duration" property in my reducer.
When I console.log the individual "collab", everything is fine. But then, I can't manage to update correctly my newState.

Do you have any idea ?

```
 export function reducer(state = initialState, action) {

  let newState = [...state];

  switch (action.type) {

   case "SEARCH_PEOPLE":
    newState = initialState;
    let results;
    axios
    .get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=${origins}&destinations=${destination}&region=FR&key=${config.gmap.key}`)
    .then(res => {
      results = res.data.rows;
      newState = newState.map((collab, i) => {
        return console.log("collab : ", {
          ...collab,
          duration: results[i].elements[0].duration.text
        })
      }
      )
    })
  return newState;

  default:
    break;
  }

 return newState;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is incorrect way. You also will need to use a redux middleware such as `redux-thunk` , `redux-saga` or any other middleware you want. This is because you are calling an API which requires `async` method while redux is synchronous when not using a middleware. I have boilerplate if you want to use `redux-saga` and understand how to implement https://github.com/sghaleb1/redux-saga-boilerplate

Comment: Thanks! Il'l check this out!

Comment: I'd recommend checking out "redux-axios-middleware" https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware. Basically, it automatically adds a `SEARCH_PEOPLE_SUCCESS` action for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is considered an [anti-pattern](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-redux-needs-reducers-to-be-pure-functions-d438c58ae468), your reducers should be pure, there should be no side effects. So put the API call inside an action creator using a [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).